# To show the closed ness of a parametric curve.

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

> Let us consider the parametric curve $f(t)=(\cos^3t \cos(3t), \cos^3t \sin(3t))$, where $t$ belongs to $\mathbb R$. Then show that the curve is closed with exactly one  self-intersection.

I know that a closed curve means if the curve is periodic for some period $T≠0$ and not constant. And the curve $f$ is said  to have a self-intersection at a point $p$ of the curve if there exist parameter values $a≠b$ such that $f(a)=f(b)=p$ and if $f$ is closed with period $T$, then $a-b$ is not an integer multiple of $T$.

I have tried to show the closedness condition but the calculation become very large.

Like: let $T$ be the period of $f$, then $f(t+T)=f(t)$ which implies two equations those are  $\cos^3(t+T)\cos3(t+T)=\cos^3t\cos(3t)$ and $\cos^3(t+T) \sin(3(t+T))=\cos^3t\sin(3t)$ but after a huge calculation failed to find the value of $T$ i.e. period.

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: the period of $\cos t$ or $\sin t$ is $2\pi$ and the period of $\cos 3t$ or $\sin 3t$ is $2\pi/3$. Thus $2\pi$ is a period of your function.

Comment: Try to simplify $f(t+\pi)$

Comment: @Masacroso. $2π$ is obviously a period. But i think $π$ must be a period here. As $cos^3(t+π) sin3(t+π)=cos^3t sin(3t)$.

Comment: if you knows that $2\pi$ is obviously a period of the function then why you asked the question?

Comment: @Masacroso. Sir I have asked for a complete solution. Intution said that it must be $π$ and since $2π$ is integral multiple of $π$ so it must be. But I can't find by solving the equation $f(t+T)=f(t)$.